# How to retrieve a nested value from the $_REQUEST dict when I have the key as a string?

Tags: php, arrays

Easiest to explain with an example. I've got an HTML form with an input like this:

```
<input name="a[b]" />
```

Now I want to retrieve the value for that input from the `$_REQUEST` dict. I have `$name = 'a[b]'`. I'm not sure how to use the string `$name` to pull the value out of `$_REQUEST` because request stores it in `$_REQUEST['a']['b']` not `$_REQUEST['a[b]']`, so `$_REQUEST[$name]` won't work.

---

Going with a modified (presumably more efficient) version of inti's solution:

```
function array_value(&$array, $key) {
    $keys = explode('[', str_replace(']', '', $key));
    $first = array_shift($keys);
    $value = $array[$first];
    foreach($keys as $k)
        $value = $value[$k];
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Uhm. Forget the comment, I did not notice a part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function like this to parse the `$name` variable:

```
function getValByName(&$req,$name)
{
    foreach(explode("[",$name) as $v)
    {
        $k = str_replace("]","",$v);
        $val = isset($val) ? $val[$k] : $req[$k];
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Usage:

```
$v = getValByName($_REQUEST,"a[b]");
$v = getValByName($_REQUEST,"a[b][c][d][e]"); // if you need more
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the $name is always nested only once, the only semi-elegant solution would be to split the $name and make a loop extracting each array one after another... I see that inti has already posted such solution.

But if you like doing things ineffective and brittle way, you can always take the raw query string and process it with some Skinner's Constants:

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&';
$name = 'a[b][c][d]';

$from = strpos($query . '=', $name) + strlen($name) + 1;
$to = strpos($query, '&', $from);
$result = urldecode(
    substr($query, $from, $to - $from)
);
```

Comment: There is no query string... it's posted.

Comment: @Mark: No problem. Just use file_get_contents("php://input") instead of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. The string format is identical. Wait: I DID write that my code is rather ineffective and brittle?

Comment: lol..then why would I use it? inti's solution seems to work well enough.

Comment: @Mark: it's in the answer. You might _like_ uneffective and brittle solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting data from form:

```
<form method="post">
  /input elements/
</form>
```

you recieve data in `$_POST` superlobal.

You can check its values using:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

If you use

```
<input type="text" name="a[b]" />
```

you can access its value by

```
$_POST['a']['b']
```

Comment: Yes... isn't that what I said in the question? I'm asking if I only have the key as a string, `a[b]`, how would I use that to pull the value out of `$_POST` (or `$_REQUEST`)?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can access it by

```
$array = $_POST['a'];
$name_value = $array['b'];
```